# Sk scene won't fit on iPad?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skscene

I'm using sprite kit; my scene won't fit on the iPad, it's like cut off, I've tried everything I know but still can't get it to work. It works fine on all the iPhones but has a problem when it comes to the iPad

Comment: We do not have the ability to read your computer or anything, my guess is you did not take aspect ratio into consideration when you were designing your app

Comment: Unless you were unaware that devices don't share the exact aspect ratio, isn't that something obvious to happen?

Answer (score 0):

1. The hard work would be to make one .sks file per iPhone/iPad size.
2. The logic part would to consider what users ""really see" in all devices: 3 to 8
3. we need to stay at first level imaging : myImage@1x.png
4. iPhone and iPad scale up and down to fit best to each other
5. take the smallest screen size and scale it up to fit to bigger devices.
6. and you will see that there is a rectangle that is always seen in all devices at any scale
7. all the parts that are off this rectangle, would be the plus parts but non essential to the main part.
8. this link helps you to do this : https://v-play.net/doc/vplay-different-screen-sizes/